# New email Server push Notification

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail API to connect to gmail inbox. What i am looking basically to create a program to listen for new emails notification in java. I find a code which adding listener in message count. Unfortunately it is not working and nothing has been updating in application if new email arrive at my gmail account. here is a code:

```
public class CheckingMails {

public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
                         String password) {
    try {

        //create properties field
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


        IMAPStore imapStore = (IMAPStore) emailSession.getStore("imaps");
       // imapStore.connect();

        imapStore.connect(host, user, password);

        final IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) imapStore.getFolder("Inbox");
        folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_WRITE);

        folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {

            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Count Event Fired");
            }

            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Removed Event fired");
            }
        });

        folder.addMessageChangedListener(new MessageChangedListener() {

            public void messageChanged(MessageChangedEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Message Changed Event fired");
            }
        });


        // Check mail once in "freq" MILLIseconds
        int freq = 2000;
        boolean supportsIdle = false;
        try {
            if (emailFolder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) emailFolder;
                f.idle();
                supportsIdle = true;
            }
        } catch (FolderClosedException fex) {
            throw fex;
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            supportsIdle = false;
        }
        for (; ; ) {
            if (supportsIdle && emailFolder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder) emailFolder;
                f.idle();
                System.out.println("IDLE done");
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(freq); // sleep for freq milliseconds

                // This is to force the IMAP server to send us
                // EXISTS notifications.
                emailFolder.getMessageCount();
            }
        }



        /*
        // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

        }

        */

        //close the store and folder objects
     //   emailFolder.close(false);
     //   store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    String mailStoreType = "pop3";
    String username = "EmailAddress@gmail.com";
    String password = "****";

    check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

}
```

}

I also added a commented code to read all emails from folder and it is working but what i am looking some kind of push notification from server. 
Can someone give me idea how i can implement this.

Comment: working with adding IMAPStore. (edit above code working)

Comment: Your code is trying to use IMAP, but it's actually using POP3.  The POP3 protocol has no way to notify you of new messages.  You need to use IMAP.

Comment: Ok but i am getting server push notification whenever new message arrived at inbox. Then why i am getting this notification?

Comment: I don't understand what notification you're getting and how you're getting it in your code.  If you use IMAP instead of POP3, your program will be able to get notifications of new messages, but if you have some other way that you're already getting notification of new messages, use that.  Still, if you need to keep using POP3, you'll need to close the folder and reopen it to see the new messages.  That's just the way the POP3 protocol works.

Comment: Well i am talking about new email notification. In above code: folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() { ... whenever i have made changes like new email arrive or i delete any email i get event in this. I am curious to know that why i am getting this event as i am using pop3? Is it because i using email session as: IMAPStore imapStore = (IMAPStore) emailSession.getStore("imaps");

Comment: Sorry, yes, that makes your code use imap, but all the pop3 properties you're setting are having no effect.  If you've changed your code and are now connecting tot he correct server and getting the events then your problem is solved, right?

Comment: @BillShannon is it good to use `for(;;)`